# Getting rate limit error in Jfrog xrays report api

Tags: java, spring, jfrog-cli, jfrog-xray

whenever i try to hit this request end point. "/xray/api/v1/reports/vulnerabilities"
. I am getting Java's IoException . with the message of
Rate limit detected, retrying later .
Any idea what could be causing this , or in which direction to look ?
Can't find much about this on internet , also it is coming in customer's account.
So not sure about what could be causing this .
Any help is appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible reasons for this error:

**Row limit:**
Xray is limiting reports to 100,000 rows by default. larger reports will fail. In order to fix that you can increase the value in the [system.yaml](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-installation-setup-documentation/xray-system-yaml) file ($JFROG_HOME/var/etc):

```
server:
  reports:
    rowLimit: 1000000
```

Another option is to use more filtered results for your report using the API payload.

**Number of reports limit**:
Xray is limiting the reports that are in the database to 100 to prevent performance issues in the work against the database.
You can increase the number but it's not recommended, instead, you can export old reports and delete them in order to generate new reports.

Comment: This Rate limit exceeded error . doesn't it seem like that the api call is not even accepted as , in rate limit on no of calls that can be made in a specific time ? Row error should throw a different message , ig no?